# Inserting data into table

Tags: java, jdbc

Good evening.

I am doing a basic exercise to insert data into an Access Database Table and in the code lies a syntax error which I am struggling to pinpoint.

Was hoping could receive some help with that as to where that Syntax problem lies.

The error reads as follow
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

```
public void addData(String ID, String name, String address, String type) throws SQLException
{
    int rowsadded;
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    String queryString = "INSERT INTO Artists(ID, Name, Address, Type) VALUES (" + ID + ", '" + name + "', '" + address + ", " + type + "')";

    System.out.println(queryString);
    System.out.println(ID + "(ID) added to the database");
    rowsadded = statement.executeUpdate(queryString);
    System.out.println("Rows updated = " + rowsadded);
}
```

Method call happens as follow

```
Insertingdata example;
    try
    {
        example = new Insertingdata();

        example.addData("15", "Bob Dylan", "Los Angeles", "Folk");

    }
    catch(SQLException se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)
    {
        ce.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a couple of single quotes in the query, so address and type were being read as a single value. Replace your queryString line with:

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO Artists(ID, Name, Address, Type) VALUES (" + ID + ", '" + name + "', '" + address + "', '" + type + "')";
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: (+1) and to avoid this kind of errors use prepared statements!